# How to handle image/binary from POST requests?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm doing an API request which returns to me an image/png content-type. After call the API and see the code 200 of it, what needs to be done to have it rendering fine on the Poster? Needs to write this output data to a temp file?

Comment: Do you need to store the image locally? Can you not use the image URL directly in a [`Poster` node](https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/references/scenegraph/renderable-nodes/poster.md)?

Comment: It was not possible to store the image locally but workaround was to use another service to get the URL instead of the binary image